# unpredictable behavior of slurm multi-cluster

Tags: slurm, hpc

I have 2 slurm clusters: **cluster A** with 3 compute nodes, each node has 32 CPUs; **Cluster B** with 4 compute nodes, each node has 8 CPUs. I'm using slurm multicluster on clusters A and B. I tried to run Nas Parallel Benchmarks (`sp.A.x`) on them.

Initially, I tried to benchmark the execution time and memory requirements (with valgrind) for the `sp.A.x` benchmark on the compute nodes on both clusters (without slurm). The obtained execution times are about 30 and 80 sec on **clusters A and B**, respectively. Then, I tried to run 3 `sbatch` jobs on each cluster (with limited memory to each job using the `--mem` option). Each job runs an instance of `sp.A.x.` But, the execution time of the `sbatch` jobs are much larger than the original benchmarks: it ranges between 34-67 sec on **cluster A**, and 100-250 sec on **cluster B**, in comparison to 30 and 80 sec of the original benchmarks. Afterwards, I removed the memory limit from the submitted jobs, then execution time of each sbatch job is reduced to the normal values, but ofcourse, each job allocates a whole node which increased the total finish time of all jobs.

I don't understand why the execution time of each job was increased in the first place?

Also, [the multicluster documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/multi_cluster.html) says:

> Slurm will immediately submit the job to the cluster that offers the
> earliest start time subject its queue of pending and running jobs.
> Slurm will make no subsequent effort to migrate the job to a different
> cluster (from the list) whose resources become available when running
> jobs finish before their scheduled end times.

So, I thought that each cluster would be allocated a number of jobs (approximately) equal to the number of CPUs at the cluster before submission to the other cluster, but this wasn't the case. I can't follow the allocation of resources based on the scheduling decision. I just can't predict the allocation of jobs to resources.

Regards